# Colspan issue in Chrome 91?

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

I think I'm losing my mind, here is some very simple code.  It works perfect in Firefox, but since the recent Chrome update (Version 91.0.4472.114), Chrome seems to ignore the width of cell 1 once colspan appears later in the table.

Any ideas?

```
<table width='773' border='3' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
     <tr>
    <td colspan='3'>Testing
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr><td width='260'>hello</td><td width='126'>hello</td><td width='387'>hello</td></tr>
<tr><td width='260'>hello</td><td colspan='2'>Nuclear fission was discovered in December 1938 by physicists Lise Meitner and Otto Frisch, and chemists Otto Hahn and Fritz Strassmann. Fission is a nuclear reaction and process of radioactive decay in which the nucleus of an atom splits into two or more smaller, lighter nuclei. The fission process releases a very large amount of energy. The discovery that a nuclear chain reaction was possible led to the development of nuclear power and nuclear weapons. Hahn and Strassmann bombarded uranium with slow neutrons, and discovered that barium had been produced (illustration pictured). Meitner and her nephew Frisch theorised, and then proved, that the uranium nucleus had been split, and published their findings in Nature. Meitner calculated that the energy released by each disintegration was approximately 200 megaelectronvolts, and Frisch observed this. By analogy with the division of biological cells, Frisch named the process "fission".</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Please post a full html example that allow us to reproduce the issue

Comment: @EliasSoares there's not much more to add except <html> to open and </html> to close.  I've stripped this back to the bare bones, but it displays completely differently in both browsers.

Comment: After further digging around, others have similar problems.  Disabling TableNG in the flags setting in Chrome fixes the issue, but it's not a solution.

Comment: Chromium browsers all have issues with colspan, but in your code everything seems to work ok. Would be better if you made a snippet and explained what exaclty is the problem